# Union groupby clause with the specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i query the group by based on id to the result to capture "yy" only if select table A UNION table B :

Table A :

```
id|field1|field2|field3

1 | xx   | yy   | xx
```

Table B :

```
id|field1|field2|field3

1 | yy   | xx   | xx
```

**The result i want :**

```
id|field1|field2|field3

1 | yy   | yy   | xx
```

Comment: This seems unclear. Posting desired output is not sufficient without an explanation of why it should be like that. Why do the `yy`s win over the `xx`s? Is this real data, or are you instead using numbers or something? Because a simple `union all` followed by a `group by id` and `max()` over each `field` would suffice in this case, but that may not reflect your real data. What are `xx` and `yy` in reality, and by what general metric is `yy` (or what it represents) preferred?

Comment: Are the table A and table B identical tables. And what is the logic of selecting 'yy' or rejecting 'xx'

Comment: There is only two value accepted which is yy and xx. For example yes and no. The "yy" value will always the higher priority than "xx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do min/max from the union:

```
select id, min(field1), min(field2), min(field3)
from (
  select id, field1, field2, field3
  from table_A
  union
  select id, field1, field2, field3
  from table_B
) as q
```

Comment: @slakso, I think you must use MAX instead of MIN as MIN will return XX while MAX will return YY.

Comment: For "xx"/"yy" yes. The question was bit unclear whether the "xx"/"yy" was the actual data or just sample data for the question.

Comment: Great ! i totally forgot about min/max aggregate functions and keep thinking of groupby. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(field1 = 'yy') > 0 then 'yy' else max(field1) end) as field1,
       (case when sum(field2 = 'yy') > 0 then 'yy' else max(field2) end) as field2,
       (case when sum(field3 = 'yy') > 0 then 'yy' else max(field3) end) as field1,
from ((select id, field1, field2, field3
       from table_A
      ) union
      (select id, field1, field2, field3
       from table_B
      ) 
     ) ab
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use natural join for this and query like this

```
select * from table1 
inner join table2
```

Comment: I would like to do a union clause for this case and not join table due to certain logic

Comment: then the best way to do this call union query and match with "YY" and replace existing value with "YY"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is that much complex so that you need to use MIN/MAX. You can try below simply -

```
SELECT A.id, B.field1, A.field2, A.field3
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B
ON A.id = B.id
```